# Variables don't work, but hard code does?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, bluebird

I'm stumped with this:

I'm using Bluebird as Promise.  For some reason, if I use the variables userProfile and allStats, I get a 404 error even though when logged out, they are IDENTICAL to the hardcoded URL.
Hell, the error response I get even lists the URL with a 404 error.

I am using a Promise based version of request also.

```
let userProfile = `https://api.lootbox.eu/${platform}/${region}/${username}/profile`;
let allStats = `https://api.lootbox.eu/${platform}/${region}/${username}/${mode}/allHeros/`;
 sails.log.info(userProfile)

return Promise.props({
    profile: request.get(`https://api.lootbox.eu/psn/eu/ohEvasive/profile`),
  stats: request.get(`https://api.lootbox.eu/psn/eu/ohEvasive/profile`),
}).then(props => {
    console.log(props.stats, props.profile);
});
```

I'm completely stumped what's causing this.  If I use the hardcoded URL (take from the log) as in my above code, the thing works fine..

I've also done a comparison just to test they're identical

```
 if(userProfile === 'https://api.lootbox.eu/psn/eu/ohEvasive/profile'){
     console.log('Identical');
 }
```

And Identical is logged out in the console

**UPDATE**

OK, so after plenty of messing around, the issue lies with the Promise.props statement.

If i only have one Prop, it works, add another and it fails

Comment: Probably the values of `platform`, `region` and `username` are not what you think they are in the scope where the string is defined.  Did you `console.log(userProfile)` at the point you're about to use it to verify it is exactly the same as the hardcoded URL?

Comment: Yep - they're exactly the same throughout the code

Comment: Uhhh, they are NOT exactly the same at the very point you are defining and using them.  Strings are strings. If they were identical you would not get a different result.  So, something is obviously different.  You will need to debug it to find out what is different.  We can't do that for you, especially because you don't show enough overall context for us to see how this is actually being used.  Your challenge is to figure out what IS different?

Comment: So when my error logs out ```options: { url: 'https://api.lootbox.eu/psn/eu/ohEvasive/profile} ``` as the URL it called, but a copy paste of that URL into Postman works...  It doesn't make sense

Comment: Are you using a promisified version of `request` because `request.get()` by itself does not return a promise so `Promise.props()` won't know what to do with it.

Comment: Yep.  Im using var request = require('request-promise');  It works as it should, but obviously the URL isn't working as I get a 404

Comment: right, so, log the string that is being generated. If it isn't exactly equal to your hardcoded one, you're doing something wrong. If it isn't, then... i can't explain it.

Comment: I've updated my post with some more findings